# ( CRM_Core_Exception: DB Error: unknown error ) when activating "Form Procees

Tags: duplicate-contacts

This error below is not the only error. We now get an error 1060
"PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/
wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 945

- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown"

When just trying to create a case.

Below is the log when activating the extension Form Process.

CRM_Core_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php on line 187
Exception trace

## Function    Location

0   civicrm_api3()  /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php:187
1   CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()    /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:578
2   CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()    /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144
3   CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform()    /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43
4   CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform()   /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
5   HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle() /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
6   HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()   /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355
7   CRM_Core_Controller->run()  /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:334
8   CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit() /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:140
9   CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()  /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php:105
10  CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run()    /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319
11  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()  /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
12  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()  /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
13  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()   /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199
14  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke() /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308
15  WP_Hook->apply_filters()    /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:332
16  WP_Hook->do_action()    /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-includes/plugin.php:517
17  do_action() /home/qbpositeadmin/qtracker.queensbp.org/wp-admin/admin.php:259
18  {main}